# Make a parser ignore all redundant whitespace

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Say I have a `Parser p` in Parsec and I want to specify that I want to ignore all superfluous/redundant white space in p. Let's for example say that I define a list as starting with "[", end with "]", and in the list are integers separated by white space. But I don't want any errors if there are white space in front of the "[", after the "]", in between the "[" and the first integer, and so on.

In my case, I want this to work for my parser for a toy programming language.

I will update with code if that is requested/necessary.

Comment: What parser are you using?  Parsec, Trifecta, something else....

Comment: @jamshidh Judging by the tags on the question, it looks like Parsec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use combinators to say what you mean:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String

program :: Parser [[Int]]
program = spaces *> many1 term <* eof

term :: Parser [Int]
term = list

list :: Parser [Int]
list = between listBegin listEnd (number `sepBy` listSeparator)

listBegin, listEnd, listSeparator :: Parser Char
listBegin = lexeme (char '[')
listEnd = lexeme (char ']')
listSeparator = lexeme (char ',')

lexeme :: Parser a -> Parser a
lexeme parser = parser <* spaces

number :: Parser Int
number = lexeme $ do
  digits <- many1 digit
  return (read digits :: Int)
```

Try it out:

```
λ :l Parse.hs
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ parseTest program " [1, 2, 3] [4, 5, 6] "
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

This `lexeme` combinator takes a parser and allows arbitrary whitespace after it. Then you only need to use `lexeme` around the primitive tokens in your language such as `listSeparator` and `number`.

Alternatively, you can parse the stream of characters into a stream of tokens, *then* parse the stream of tokens into a parse tree. That way, both the lexer and parser can be greatly simplified. It’s only worth doing for larger grammars, though, where maintainability is a concern; and you have to use some of the lower-level Parsec API such as `tokenPrim`.

Answer (score 3):

Just surround everything with `space`:

```
parseIntList :: Parsec String u [Int]
parseIntList = do
    spaces
    char '['
    spaces
    first <- many1 digit
    rest <- many $ try $ do
        spaces
        char ','
        spaces
        many1 digit
    spaces
    char ']'
    return $ map read $ first : rest
```

This is a very basic one, there are cases where it'll fail (such as an empty list) but it's a good start towards getting something to work.

@Joehillen's suggestion will also work, but it requires some more type magic to use the token features of Parsec.  The definition of `spaces` matches 0 or more characters that satisfies `Data.Char.isSpace`, which is all the standard ASCII space characters.